# Do each one of these threads wait until the mutex is unlocked to perform a function?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

Below is a mutex lock program from my systems class. It creates a new thread for each letter in an input string and then converts every other letter to upper case. 
My question is, do threads in c actually "wait" for the mutex to unlock before performing a function? Or do they just fail the operation if the method is locked?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define SIZE 50

char sentence[2000];
int  ind = 0;

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;

void
increment_ind()
{
    ind = ind + 1;    
}

char convertUppercase(char lower)
{
    //Converts lowercase un uppercase
    if ((lower > 96) && (lower < 123))
        return (lower - 32);
    else
        return lower;
}

void printChar()
{
    //prints the converted sentence
    printf("The new sentence is [%d]: \t%c\n", ind, sentence[ind]);
    increment_ind();
}

void *convertMessage(void *ptr)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);   

    // Function that each threads initiates its execution
    char aux;

    if (ind % 2)
        sentence[ind] = convertUppercase(sentence[ind]);

    printChar();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char buffer[SIZE];
    char *p;
    pthread_t ts[SIZE]; // define up to 50 threads

    printf("Please enter a phrase (less than 50 characters): ");

    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL_
        if ((p = strchr(buffer, '\n')) != NULL)
            *p = '\0';

    strcpy(sentence, buffer);
    printf("The original sentence is: \t %s\n", sentence);

    // create one thread for each character on the input word
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(buffer) + 1; ++i)
        pthread_create(&ts[i], NULL, convertMessage, NULL);

    // we wait until all threads finish execution
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
        pthread_join(ts[i], NULL);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pthread_mutex_lock` is a blocking call, so if a thread (or threads) arrives here and the mutex is locked, it will block (wait) until it can acquire the mutex. This requires the thread that owns the mutex to unlock it first. There is a `pthread_mutex_trylock`(http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) that is non-blocking. Also, you must initialize your mutex before you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, threads in general wait for the mutex to become available, but not yours.  I assume the reason you're asking this question is your threads are all ignoring the mutex.  The reason they are is in `main()` you forgot to call:

```
pthread_mutex_init(&count_mutex, NULL);
```

And worse than that, you forgot to check the return value of:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
```

which is spitting out error code 22 due to the uninitialized mutex!

Below is my rework of your code to address the above, fix other errors (you launched one more thread than you joined, etc.), plus some style tweaks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define SIZE 50

char sentence[2000];
int ind = 0;

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;

void increment_ind()
{
    ind = ind + 1;
}

char convertUppercase(char character)
{
    // Converts lowercase to uppercase
    if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z')
    {
        character -= ' ';
    }

    return character;
}

void printSentence()
{
    // prints the converted sentence
    printf("The new sentence is [%d]: %s\n", ind, sentence);
}

void *convertMessage(void *pointer)
{
    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex) == 0)
    {
        // Function that each threads initiates its execution
        if (ind % 2 == 1)
        {
            sentence[ind] = convertUppercase(sentence[ind]);
        }

        printSentence();

        increment_ind();

        (void) pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
    }
    else
    {
        /* handle the error! */
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    char *p, buffer[SIZE];
    pthread_t threads[SIZE]; // define up to 50 threads

    (void) pthread_mutex_init(&count_mutex, NULL);

    printf("Please enter a phrase (less than 50 characters): ");

    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL)
    {
        /* print an error message to stderr */
        return 1;
    }

    if ((p = strchr(buffer, '\n')) != NULL)
    {
        *p = '\0';
    }

    (void) strcpy(sentence, buffer); // copy local string to global string

    printf("The original sentence is: %s\n", sentence);

    // create one thread for each character in the input string
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
    {
        (void) pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, convertMessage, NULL);
    }

    // we wait until all threads finish execution
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
    {
        (void) pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. This is actually an example provided by my professor! I had no idea it wasn't good code.

Answer (score 1):

From the [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html):

> The mutex object referenced by mutex shall be locked by a call to
>   pthread_mutex_lock() that returns zero or [EOWNERDEAD]. **If the mutex
>   is already locked by another thread, the calling thread shall block
>   until the mutex becomes available.** This operation shall return with
>   the mutex object referenced by mutex in the locked state with the
>   calling thread as its owner.

(emphasis mine)

So, yes the thread "waits" for the mutex to become available (unless an error occurs). When `pthread_mutex_lock()` returns, the calling thread has acquired the lock. But it might return with errors as well. That's why you should check the return value.